# sed/awk/cut/grep - Best way to extract string

Tags: sed, awk, grep, cut

I have a results.txt  file that is structured in this format:

```
Uncharted 3: Javithaxx l Rampant l Graveyard l Team Deathmatch HD (D1VpWBaxR8c)
Matt Darey feat. Kate Louise Smith - See The Sun (Toby Hedges Remix) (EQHdC_gGnA0)
The Matrix State (SXP06Oax70o)
Above & Beyond - Group Therapy Radio 014 (guest Lange) (2013-02-08) (8aOdRACuXiU)
```

I want to create a new file extracting the youtube URL ID specified in the last characters in each line line "8aOdRACuXiU"

I'm trying to build a URL like this in a new file:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aOdRACuXiU&hd=1

Note, I appended the &hd=1 to the string that I am trying to be replaced. I have tried using Linux reverse and cut but reverse or rev munges my data. The hard part here is that each line in my text file will have entries with parentheses and I only care about getting the data between the last set of parentheses. Each line has a variable length so that isn't helpful either. What about using grep and .$ for the end of the line?

In summary, I want to extract the youtube ID from results.txt and export it to a new file in the following format: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aOdRACuXiU&hd=1

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{ 
  v = substr( $NF, 2, length( $NF ) - 2 )
  printf "%s%s%s\n", "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=", v, "&hd=1" 
}' infile
```

It yields:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D1VpWBaxR8c&hd=1
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EQHdC_gGnA0&hd=1
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SXP06Oax70o&hd=1
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aOdRACuXiU&hd=1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed 's!.*(\(.*\))!http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=\1\&hd=1!' results.txt 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D1VpWBaxR8c&hd=1
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EQHdC_gGnA0&hd=1
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SXP06Oax70o&hd=1
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aOdRACuXiU&hd=1
```

Here, `.*(\(.*\))` looks for the last occurrence of a pair of parentheses, and captures the characters inside those parentheses. The captured group is then inserted into the URL using `\1`.

Answer (score 1):

Using a [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) one-liner :

```
perl -lne 'printf "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%s&hd=1\n", $& if /[^\(]+(?=\)$)/' file.txt
```

Or multi-line version :

```
perl -lne '
    printf(
        "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%s&hd=1\n",
        $&
    ) if /[^\(]+(?=\)$)/
' file.txt
```